# How do I get Directory entries in a specific OU

Tags: c#, winforms, active-directory

I have the following code...

```
 // List of strings for your names
            List<string> allUsers = new List<string>();



            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "bellbain.local"))
            {
                using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
                {
                    foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                        //  allUsers.Add(("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value));
                        allUsers.Add(de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString());


                    }
                }
            }
            listBox1.DataSource = allUsers;
```

This works fine creating a list of all my usernames, however I would like only a list of usernames in a specific OU. I have found examples on line but cant understand exactly how to apply them to my situation.

the 'tree' in Active directory is

mydomain.local > MyBusiness > Users > SBSUsers > TestDept

I need a list of only the users in the Test Dept OU.

I tried this...

// List of strings for your names
        List allUsers = new List();

```
    string ou = "OU=TestDept,DC=mydomain.local";

    using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "bellbain.local",ou))
    {
        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
        {
            foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
            {
                DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                //  allUsers.Add(("First Name: " + de.Properties["givenName"].Value));
                allUsers.Add(de.Properties["sAMAccountName"].Value.ToString());


            }
        }
    }
    listBox1.DataSource = allUsers;
```

However the list box is empty...

Comment: Well your string looks like its doing that - depending on how your ad is laid out.  So how is the above not working? other than you dont seem to use your ou string?

Comment: My mistake the string was part of a failed attempt, i have now removed it.

Comment: Shame, that was a useful portion

Comment: thought it would be cleared like this as the string did not work. should i put it back?

Comment: Thanks for tips, any ideas about a solution?